# Sending a file over TCP sockets in Python

Tags: python, file, sockets, python-2.7, tcp

I've successfully been able to copy the file contents (image) to a new file. However when I try the same thing over TCP sockets I'm facing issues. The server loop is not exiting. The client loop exits when it reaches the EOF, however the server is unable to recognize EOF.

Here's the code:

**Server**

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
f = open('torecv.png','wb')
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    print "Receiving..."
    l = c.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        print "Receiving..."
        f.write(l)
        l = c.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    print "Done Receiving"
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()                # Close the connection
```

**Client**

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!")
f = open('tosend.png','rb')
print 'Sending...'
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    print 'Sending...'
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
f.close()
print "Done Sending"
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

Here's the screenshot:

**Server**
[image: Server]

**Client**
[image: Client]

Edit 1: Extra data copied over. Making the file "not complete."
The first column shows the image that has been received. It seems to be larger than the one sent. Because of this, I'm not able to open the image. It seems like a corrupted file.

[image: File sizes]

Edit 2: This is how I do it in the console. The file sizes are the same here.
[image: Python Console]
[image: Same file sizes]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Client need to notify that it finished sending, using [`socket.shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) (not [`socket.close`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) which close both reading/writing part of the socket):

```
...
print "Done Sending"
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

**UPDATE**

Client sends `Hello server!` to the server; which is written to the file in the server side.

```
s.send("Hello server!")
```

Remove above line to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I tried this, but it's still in the loop. The problem I think is that the client send is never sending the EOF, because once it reaches EOF, it's breaking out of the loop and never sending it to the server. Is that the error?

Comment: @SwaathiK, Ah, client is waiting for the data, after it finish sending. I updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked like a charm. But I just have one more question, why is the file not being reconstructed on the server side? It copies everything, but the file is not complete. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @SwaathiK, What does it mean by `the file is not compelte`?

Comment: When I do the same operation in the console, it seems to work. I've added the screenshots to the question.

Comment: @SwaathiK, Please replace `send`s with `sendall`, and try again.

Comment: It's (torecv.png) still the same file size, 58,055 bytes. :(

Answer (score 6):

Remove below code

```
s.send("Hello server!")
```

because your sending `s.send("Hello server!")` to server, so your output file is somewhat more in size.

Answer (score 2):

**You can send some flag to stop while loop in server**

**for example**

## Server side:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost", 5000))
s.listen(1)
c,a = s.accept()
filetodown = open("img.png", "wb")
while True:
   print("Receiving....")
   data = c.recv(1024)
   if data == b"DONE":
           print("Done Receiving.")
           break
   filetodown.write(data)
filetodown.close()
c.send("Thank you for connecting.")
c.shutdown(2)
c.close()
s.close()
#Done :)
```

## Client side:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 5000))
filetosend = open("img.png", "rb")
data = filetosend.read(1024)
while data:
    print("Sending...")
    s.send(data)
    data = filetosend.read(1024)
filetosend.close()
s.send(b"DONE")
print("Done Sending.")
print(s.recv(1024))
s.shutdown(2)
s.close()
#Done :)
```

Comment: 1. filetodown.write(data)
    filetodown.flush() #add this to aviod file corruption
2.below code is not work for me.
if data == b"DONE":
           print("Done Receiving.")
           break
but, I modify below code is work.
   if data <1024: #your read buffer.
           print("Done Receiving.")
           break

Answer (score 1):

The problem is extra 13 byte which server.py receives at the start. To resolve that write "l = c.recv(1024)" twice before the while loop as below.

```
print "Receiving..."
l = c.recv(1024) #this receives 13 bytes which is corrupting the data
l = c.recv(1024) # Now actual data starts receiving
while (l):
```

This resolves the issue, tried with different format and sizes of files. If anyone knows what this starting 13 bytes refers to, please reply.

Comment: I think that "Hello server!" is the 13 bytes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put file inside `while True` like so

```
while True:
     f = open('torecv.png','wb')
     c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
     print 'Got connection from', addr
     print "Receiving..."
     l = c.recv(1024)
     while (l):
         print "Receiving..."
         f.write(l)
         l = c.recv(1024)
     f.close()
     print "Done Receiving"
     c.send('Thank you for connecting')
     c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you may change your loop condition according to following code, when length of l is smaller than buffer size it means that it reached end of file

```
while (True):
    print "Receiving..."
    l = c.recv(1024)        
    f.write(l)
    if len(l) < 1024:
        break
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct answer because this assumes that the file is exactly a multiple of 1024. If the last data packet is, say, 800, it will be ignored.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship nope, it will be written. The condition is AFTER the write op.

Answer (score 0):

This is a top Google result for "send a file through a socket in Python".

The fastest way to send a file through a socket in Python is to use [socket.sendfile](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendfile), introduced in Python 3.5:

```py
socket.sendfile(fileobj)
```

`socket.sendfile` uses [os.sendfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) (and the [sendfile syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)) to perform a high-speed file copy whenever possible and falls back to `socket.send` otherwise.