# Sending numpy arrays via Socket

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, numpy, pickle

First of all, what I want to do:
Sending Photos with Socket from my Raspberry Pi to my laptop.

**Client:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pickle

#Upload image
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image', 0)

#Turn image into numpy-array
arr = np.asarray(img)

#Receiver ip
ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"

#Set up socket and stuff 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#Loop through each array (5 for test)
for each in range(5):

    #Encode each array
    msg = pickle.dumps(arr[each][0])

    #Send msg to ip with port
    s.sendto(msg, (ip, 50000))

s.close()
```

What happens here:
I upload a picture and then turn it into an Numpy array. Then I take each line of the array (each list) and "encode" it with pickle to send it afterwards via Socket. Everything works fine to this point.

**Server:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind(("", 50000)) 

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
    conv = pickle.loads(data)
    print conv
    #print np.fromstring(conv,dtype=int)
s.close()
```

The server receives the encoded data and decodes it back into an Numpy array (that's what I want to achieve).

At the end, it should turn the array back into an image, but I didn't even get to that part, because of the issues I have at this point.

I've also tried to turn the array into a string first, encode it with pickle and then send it so when it gets decoded, it is an numpy array. But that didn't work well.

*ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size*

I would appreciate any kind of help, be it a link or pointing out my mistake.
Have been working on this for days and haven't found anything that could help me in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you  don't send image directly as bytes - `fh = open(... "rb")`, `sendto(fh.read())`

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? How does the sendto() function work?
I'm actually quite new to socket and all that stuff, that's why ^^

Comment: Nevermind, I now understand what you mean, but the message gets too long, so it doesn't work. Is there a way to split the data into packages so I send them like that?

`socket.error: [Errno 90] Message too long`

Comment: you don't have to convert bytes from file into string (or any other thing) to send it. `pickle` converts Python object into bytes. `sendto()` always sends bytes.

Comment: btw. if client sends data longer then 4096 then server has to use `recvfrom(4096)` in loop to receive all data. Problem is server doesn't know how many times use `recvfrom(4096)` so first you should send `size` - and this way you create own "protocol" like other protocols ie. HTTP, FTP. So it is easier to use HTTP.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!
Now I have to find a way to turn the bytes back into a picture.

Comment: if you write bytes in file then you get image file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need OpenCV and NumPy for this.  Instead, simply send the bytes of the file directly.  If you have Python 3.5 you can even use `socket.sendfile()`.

For more detail see: [Sending a file over TCP sockets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241804/sending-a-file-over-tcp-sockets-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, but I have already solved it the way furas told me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how many decimal places you need but you could encode your numpy array values in UTF16 BE and then decode after socket send with

```
def retrieve_and_decode_data():
    try:
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(4096)                                                                                                                                                                                
        list_of_converted_utf16chars = (repr(data.decode('utf-16')).split("\\")[1:])

    except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
        **perform some conversion-error exception...**
```

The "repr" function gives you a representation of the utf16 char you can look up in the utf-table

you can then convert this representation into a int or float with

```
integer_value = int(list_of_converted_utf16chars[index], 16)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already solved it the way furas told me